# MySQL Percentage per hour

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot, average

I have a MySQL table as follows:

[image]

So far I've been able to get the success percentage as follows:

```
SELECT endDate AS TIME
        ,count(*) * 100.0 / (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM test_result
            WHERE endDate BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1603947600)
                    AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1604006628)
                AND testResult IN (
                    "SUCCESS"
                    ,"FAILURE"
                    )
            ) AS "Percent"
    FROM test_result
    WHERE endDate BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1603947600)
            AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1604006628)
        AND testResult = "SUCCESS"
    GROUP BY 1
        ,testResult
```

But I was tasked to make this into a graph showing the percentage change throughout the day (per hour).

This is my latest failure attempt:

```
SELECT count(*) AS Count
        ,CONCAT (
            month(endDate)
            ,'-'
            ,day(endDate)
            ,'-'
            ,hour(endDate)
            ) AS hour
        ,testResult
    FROM test_result
    WHERE testResult IN (
            'SUCCESS'
            ,'FAILURE'
            )
    GROUP BY testResult
        ,hour
    ORDER BY hour
```

Any hints?

Comment: Functions cannot use indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the success rate per hour of `endDate`, then you can do:

```
select
    date_format(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') endHour,
    avg(testResult = 'FAILURE') failure_ratio
from test_result
where testResult in ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE')
group by endHour
order by endHour
```

The `date_format()` expression truncates `endDate` to the hour: you can use that information to aggregate. On the other hand `avg()` computes the ratio of "FAILURE"s in `testResult`: that's a decimal between `0` and `1`, that you can multiply by `100` to get a percentage.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the date as a date? I need it to be still a date.

Comment: @javydreamercsw: `date_format()` returns a string, but MySQL will happily treat it as a `datetime`, because its format is consistent with what MySQL expects. If you *really* want a date(time), then you can cast it back, like `cast(date_format(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as datetime)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT endDate as time,
       AVG(CASE WHEN testResult = 'SUCCESS' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM test_result
WHERE endDate BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1603947600) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1604006628) AND
      testResult IN ('SUCCESS', 'FAILURE')
GROUP BY 1
```